# EmguCV: Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

When publishing project to windows server 2003 (old test machine) I get following error when trying to call open cv functions.

Additional information: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

I am using EmguCV 3.4.1 version with uploaded libraries:

```
vcruntime140.dll
opencv_ffmpeg341.dll
msvcp140.dll
cvextern.dll
concrt140.dll
```

To the Emgu package nothing extra (dll's) were added and on developer machine I could develop the application.

I keep wondering whether additional native dll's should be added. I downloaded binaries for 3.4.1 version. The files go like that:

```
opencv_core249.dll
opencv_highgui249.dll
```

Those two above where in 3.4.1 package. When i copied them to program directory it didn't help either.

What's more I have no idea how to track down the problem.

Process monitor doesn't show that the process is looking for something that cannot be loaded.

In the inner exception I am given only this exception: Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Comment: `opencv_core249.dll` is for OpenCV 2.4.9 -- It won't be any help making 3.4.1 work.

Comment: It might be worth inspecting `cvextern.dll` on the test machine with a [Dependency walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and see what it needs that is missing. (From what I've seen in the distribution package, the DLL is large enough to contain the C++ implementation, so no further openCV libs other than ffmpeg should be needed...)

Answer (score 1):

I had to install "Desktop Experience" feature on my server. Because server 2003 doesn't seem to have it, I had to move it to another server 2008 host.